# SQL Server : column alias accessing

Tags: sql-server

I have a query that looks like this:

```
Select (numberLateOrders / numberOfOrders) as percentFailed
From Orders
```

Now I wanted to be able to add a `Where` clause and access the column alias `percentFailed` however it seems like the alias is not being recognized until the query completes. Is this true and/or is there a work around for this?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Just to add to the existing answers*

Or do it with a Subquery

```
select
  percentFailed
from (
  Select (numberLateOrders / numberOfOrders) as percentFailed
  From Orders
) t
where
  percentFailed > 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's true, the column alias won't be accessible/available in `WHERE` clause because of the logical order of execution in SQL and per that `SELECT column alias` comes after `WHERE` and so `WHERE` won't be able to recognize them. You will have to add the computation/expression in `WHERE` again like below

```
Select (numberLateOrders / numberOfOrders) as percentFailed
From Orders
WHERE (numberLateOrders / numberOfOrders) > some_value
```

Another solution (not better one) is to use a outer query like

```
select percentFailed
from 
(
    Select (numberLateOrders / numberOfOrders) as percentFailed
    From Orders 
) tab
where percentFailed > some_value
```

Answer (score 1):

WHERE can`t see aliases,just repeat the expression

```
Select (numberLateOrders / numberOfOrders) as percentFailed
From Orders
WHERE (numberLateOrders / numberOfOrders) >0
```